# Does convergence of integrals imply a.e. convergence of functions?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{u_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq L^{\infty}([0,T],U)$ be a sequence of measurable functions, where $U=[0,\overline u]$ is a compact set, and suppose that $\lambda(t,du)$ is a probability kernel on $[0,T]\times \mathcal B(U)$ (where $\mathcal B(U)$ is the class of Borel sets of $U$) such that for every interval $I=(a,b]\subseteq[0,T]$ and for all continuous and bounded function $g:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{equation}
\int_I \left[\,g(u_n(t))-\mathcal{L}g(t)\,\right]dt \stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
\end{equation}
holds, with $\mathcal{L}g(t)=\int_U g(u)\lambda(t,du)$. I have two questions:

- Is it true that the previous relation holds for all $I\in\mathcal{B}([0,T])$?
- If the answer to the previous question is affirmative, does it imply that 
  \begin{equation}
  \,g(u_n(t))-\mathcal{L}g(t)\,\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0, \quad t-a.e. [0,T]\,\,?
  \end{equation}

(this question is related to weak convergence of relaxed controls).